# How to index into a data frame using another data frame's indices?

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe, `num_buys_per_day`

```
        Date  count
0 2011-01-13      1
1 2011-02-02      1
2 2011-03-03      2
3 2011-06-03      1
4 2011-08-01      1
```

I have another data frame `commissions_buy` which I'll give a small subset of:

```
            num_orders
2011-01-10           0
2011-01-11           0
2011-01-12           0
2011-01-13           0
2011-01-14           0
2011-01-18           0
```

I want to apply the following command

```
commissions_buy.loc[num_buys_per_day.index, :] = num_buys_per_day.values * commission
```

where `commission` is a scalar.

Note that all indices in `num_buys_per_day` exist in `commissions_buy`.

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Timestamp' and 'float'
```

How should I do the correct command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to first make the Date colum to the index:

```
num_buys_per_day.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
commission_buy.loc[num_buys_per_day.index, 'num_orders'] = num_buys_per_day['count'].values * commission
```

Comment: Which `df`? Thanks

Comment: I renamed the dataframe according to your example (df was refering to num_buys_per_day)